# Google Cloud Build - Results doesn't save across steps

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I use [Remote builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/remote-builder) community image to download some protected dependencies from internal GC ComputeEngine instance.

This step in the **cloudbuild.yaml** looks like:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/{PROJECT_NAME}/remote-builder
  env:
  - COMMAND=sudo bash workspace/build.bash
  - ZONE=us-east1-b
  - INSTANCE_NAME=remote-cloud-build
  - INSTANCE_ARGS=--image-project centos-cloud --image-family centos-7
```

**build.bash:**

```
easy_install pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip wheel  -r workspace/requirements.txt -w workspace/requirements --no-binary :all:
```

So I copied my libraries to the `workspace/requirements` folder.
But there are no files in this folder on the next build step.
I've tried to create empty file inside the folder for test like: `touch workspace/requirements/file`, but folder is still empty.
Could you please help me with it.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps explains that the `/workspace` directory is mounted in every step.

I think you are in the `/workspace` directory, when `build.bash` is executed, so it could be that you generate a `workspace` dir in a `workspace` dir: `/workspace/workspace`.

Can you try to put a `/` in front `workspace`?

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/{PROJECT_NAME}/remote-builder
  env:
  - COMMAND=sudo bash /workspace/build.bash
  - ZONE=us-east1-b
  - INSTANCE_NAME=remote-cloud-build
  - INSTANCE_ARGS=--image-project centos-cloud --image-family centos-7
```

and

```
easy_install pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip wheel  -r /workspace/requirements.txt -w /workspace/requirements --no-binary :all:
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. Thank you very much for the answer